# for comprehension in scala with recursive call

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

I am working on the last project for the coursera course "functional programming in scala". I need to implement a function called combinations that takes a list of character occurrences and output all possible subsets of character occurrences. As an example, the subsets of the occurrence list `List(('a', 2), ('b', 2))` are:

```
List(
  List(),
  List(('a', 1)),
  List(('a', 2)),
  List(('b', 1)),
  List(('a', 1), ('b', 1)),
  List(('a', 2), ('b', 1)),
  List(('b', 2)),
  List(('a', 1), ('b', 2)),
  List(('a', 2), ('b', 2))
)
```

My approach to this problem is to loop through each character (such as 'a'), and take its possible occurrence counts (from 0 to 2), and prepand this to the current subset. Then proceed to the next character and repeat until I hit the end of the list, which is caught by the base case. I implemented this with a for comprehension like below:

```
type Occurrences = List[(Char, Int)]

def combinations(occurrences: Occurrences): List[Occurrences] =
  if (occurrences == List()) List() // base case
  else
    for {
      (c, n) <- occurrences
      subc <- combinations((occurrences.toMap - c).toList)
      i <- 0 to n
    } yield {
      if (i == 0) subc // not including c in the subset
      else (c, i) :: subc // including c in the subset
    }
```

This function always gives me an empty list when I call `combinations(List(('a', 2), ('b', 2))`. Any ideas why this is the case?

Comment: I realize that the "solution" is wrong even if it gives me my intended outcome as there will be many duplicates due to the way I looped through the elements in the collection. What I don't get is why I get an empty list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the unexpected output is here:

```
subc <- combinations((occurrences.toMap - c).toList)
```

This will recurse, loading the stack frame, until eventually returning the base case `List()`.  Now, remember that in a `for` comprehension the generators (`<-`) are implemented via `map` or `flatMap`, and once you map on an empty collection you're done.

```
List[Int]().map(_ + 1).foreach(_ => println("got it"))  // no output
```

So the following generator, `i <- 0 to n`, is not invoked, there is nothing to `yield` and the empty `List()` is the only thing to return. Then the stack frame pops, the empty `List()` is received, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the line:

```
subc <- combinations((occurrences.toMap - c).toList)
```

In the call just above the base case, this is evaluated to `List()` which hamstrings your for-comprehension:

```
scala> for {a <- 0 to 3; b <- List()} yield a
res0: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector()
```

Which makes that call return `List()` and so on, meaning that you are returning empty lists all the way up the call stack, which is why you get a `List()` at the top.