# Scala Recursive For Comprehension Prepends Empty List Only Once, Why?

Tags: scala, recursion, for-comprehension

similar to this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41471322/for-comprehension-in-scala-with-recursive-call), I am working on the "Functional Programming in Scala" Anagrams coursework. I could not figure out the combinations function, but found this incredibly elegant solution elsewhere

```
def combinations(occurrences: Occurrences): List[Occurrences] =
  List() :: (for {
    (char, max) <- occurrences
    count <- 1 to max
    rest <- combinations(occurrences filter {case (c, _) => c > char})
  } yield List((char, count)) ++ rest)
```

I understand how the for the comprehension works to create the combinations, but what I do not understand is why the empty list is not pre-appended to every inner list during each recursive call. It's almost as if the compiler skips the prepend statement and only executes the right side for expression.

For example, the input `combinations(List(('a', 2), ('b', 2)))` returns the expected result set:

```
res1: List[forcomp.Anagrams.Occurrences] = List(List(), List((a,1)), List((a,1), (b,1)), List((a,1), (b,2)), List((a,2)), List((a,2), (b,1)), List((a,2), (b,2)), List((b,1)), List((b,2)))
```

With only a single Empty list. Looking at the recursive call, I would expected another Empty list for each recursion. Would someone be so kind as to explain how this elegant solution works?

Comment: Note that `List((char, count)) ++ res` makes the whole thing extremely inefficient. Do this instead `(char, count) :: res`

Comment: `::` results in a type error

```type mismatch;
 found   : List[List[Equals with java.io.Serializable]]
 required: List[forcomp.Anagrams.Occurrences]
    (which expands to)  List[List[(Char, Int)]]
    List() :: (for {```

Comment: No, it doesn't: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/SwM22gLuRt2rmpz2h6EFDA/8 - btw, `combinations2` is my own solution to the problem.

Comment: Ah I see thank you.

Comment: Jonny, please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing producing an empty list inside this for comprehension. Even if

```
combinations(occurrences filter {case (c, _) => c > char})
```

contained an empty list and returned it in `rest <- ...` (it should for the first element), a value is prepended in `List((char, count)) ++ rest` making it non-empty by design.

So the whole for-comprehension must return a `List` of non-empty `List`s to which an empty list is prepended.

This basically builds solution by induction:

- if you have an empty list - return an empty list because it is a valid solution for this input
- if you start with `(char, maxOccurrences) :: rest`

  - assume that you have a valid solution for `combinations(rest)`
  - then take each such solution and add `(char, 1)` to each element of `rest`,
  - then take each such solution and add `(char, 2)` to each element of `rest`,
  - ...
  - then take each such solution and add `(char, maxOccurrences)` to each element of `rest`
  - then combine all of these results into one solution
  - all of these are non-empty because you *always* prepended something
  - so you are missing empty set, so you add it explicitly to all the other solutions combined to create a complete solution for `(char, maxOccurrences) :: rest`

Because you have a valid starting point and a valid way of creating next step from the previous, you know that you can always create a valid solution.

In the for comprehension

```
  def combinations(occurrences: Occurrences): List[Occurrences] =
    List() :: (for {
      (char, max) <- occurrences
      count <- 1 to max
      rest <- combinations(occurrences filter {case (c, _) => c > char})
    } yield List((char, count)) ++ rest)
```

is doing the same thing as

```
def combinations(occurrences: Occurrences): List[Occurrences] =
  List() :: occurrences.flatMap { case (char, max) =>
    (1 to map).flatMap { count =>
      combinations(occurrences filter {case (c, _) => c > char}).map { rest =>
        (char, count) :: rest
      }
    }
  }
```

which is the same as

```
def combinations(occurrences: Occurrences): List[Occurrences] =
  occurrences.map { case (char, max) =>
    (1 to map).map { count =>
      val newOccurence = (char, count)
      combinations(occurrences filter {case (c, _) => c > char}).map { rest =>
        newOccurence :: rest
      }
    }
  }.flatten.flatten.::(List())
```

and this you can easily compare to the induction recipe from above:

```
def combinations(occurrences: Occurrences): List[Occurrences] =
  occurrences.map { case (char, max) =>
    // for every character on the list of occurrences
    (1 to max).map { count =>
      // you construct (char, 1), (char, 2), ... (char, max)
      val newOccurence = (char, count)
      // and for each such occurrence
      combinations(occurrences filter {case (c, _) => c > char}).map { rest =>
        // you prepend it into every result from smaller subproblem
        newOccurence :: rest
      }
    }
  }
   // because you would have a List(List(List(List(...)))) here
   // and you need List(List(...)) you flatten it twice
  .flatten.flatten
  // and since you are missing empty result, you prepend it here
  .::(List())
```

The solution you posted does exactly the same thing just in more compacted way - instead of `.map().flatten`, there are `.flatMap`s hidden by a for-comprehension.

Comment: When you write

"Even if `rest` contained an empty list and returned it in rest <- ... (it should for the first element), a value is prepended in List((char, count)) ++ rest making it non-empty by design."

I don't understand why `rest` does not always contain the empty list because prepending is the first step of occurrences. Every time we add something to rest would we not include that empty list?

Answer (score 2):

I think that tracking the calls will help you understand it better. I am going to number the steps to easily going back and forth between them.

1. `combinations(List(('a', 2), ('b', 2)))`, we have first:

   ```
   (char, max) <- ('a', 2)
   count <- 1
   ```

   The result of `occurrences filter {case (c, _) => c > char}` will be `List(('b', 2))`.
2. Therefore we now calculate `combinations(List(('b', 2)))`:

   ```
   (char, max) <- ('b', 2)
   count <- 1
   ```

   Now, the result of `occurrences filter {case (c, _) => c > char}` will be `List()`.
3. We are going to calculate `combiantions(List())`:

   The for comprehension will be `List()`, and `List() :: List()` results in `List()`. Therefore we are back in step 2:
4. (step 2) We had:

   ```
   (char, max) <- ('b', 2)
   count <- 1
   ```

   and now we have no elements for rest. So the result of step 2 will be `List() :: List()` which is `List()` as well. Back to step 1. So we are going to yield for that option `List((char, count)) ++ rest)` which is: `List(('b', 1)) ++ List())` which is `List(('b', 1))` We are now in the next iteration of the same call with:

   ```
   (char, max) <- ('b', 2)
   count <- 2
   ```

   `rest` will be `List()` again and we are now going to yield for that option `List((char, count)) ++ rest)` which is: `List(('b', 2)) ++ List())` which is `List(('b', 2))`. Now we have to add the empty list, and the result is: `List(List(), List((b,1)), List((b,2)))`.
5. (step 1) We had:

   ```
   (char, max) <- ('a', 2)
   count <- 1
   ```

   and now we have:

   ```
   rest <- List()
   ```

   So we are yielding `List((char, count)) ++ rest` which is: `List(('a', 1)) ++ List()` which is: `List(('a', 1))`

   Now we continue to:

   ```
   rest <- List((b,1))
   ```

   So we are yielding `List((char, count)) ++ rest` which is: `List(('a', 1)) ++ List((b,1))` which is: `List(('a', 1), ('b', 1))`.

   Now we continue to:

   ```
   rest <- List((b,2))
   ```

   So we are yielding `List((char, count)) ++ rest` which is: `List(('a', 1)) ++ List((b,2))` which is: `List(('a', 1), ('b', 2))`. The aggregated result so far is:

   ```
    List(List(('a', 1)), List(('a', 1), ('b', 1)), List(('a', 1), ('b', 2)))
   ```

Now `max` is going to be increase to 2, and we are going to do the same calculation in steps 2-4, which are going to yield, with the exact same logic:

```
List(List(('a', 2)), List(('a', 2), ('b', 1)), List(('a', 2), ('b', 2)))
```

And now `(char, max)` is going to be changed into `('b', 2)`, which will result it(after applying the same logic from steps 2-4):

```
List(List(('b', 1)), List(('b', 2)))
```

When aggregating all together, with the prior empty list we get the wanted output.

What really helps to see what I just explained, is adding printing messages:

```
def combinations(occurrences: Occurrences): List[Occurrences] = {
  println("Starting with: " + occurrences)
  val result = List() :: (for {
    (char, max) <- occurrences
    count <- 1 to max
    rest <- combinations(occurrences filter {case (c, _) => c > char })
  } yield {
    val result = List((char, count)) ++ rest
    println("Occurrences are: " + occurrences + " Result is: " + result)
    result
  })
  println("Done with: " + occurrences + " results are: " + result)
  result
}
```

Then the call `println("Done: " + combinations(List(('a', 2), ('b', 2))))` results in:

```
Starting with: List((a,2), (b,2))
Starting with: List((b,2))
Starting with: List()
Done with: List() results are: List(List())
Occurrences are: List((b,2)) Result is: List((b,1))
Starting with: List()
Done with: List() results are: List(List())
Occurrences are: List((b,2)) Result is: List((b,2))
Done with: List((b,2)) results are: List(List(), List((b,1)), List((b,2)))
Occurrences are: List((a,2), (b,2)) Result is: List((a,1))
Occurrences are: List((a,2), (b,2)) Result is: List((a,1), (b,1))
Occurrences are: List((a,2), (b,2)) Result is: List((a,1), (b,2))
Starting with: List((b,2))
Starting with: List()
Done with: List() results are: List(List())
Occurrences are: List((b,2)) Result is: List((b,1))
Starting with: List()
Done with: List() results are: List(List())
Occurrences are: List((b,2)) Result is: List((b,2))
Done with: List((b,2)) results are: List(List(), List((b,1)), List((b,2)))
Occurrences are: List((a,2), (b,2)) Result is: List((a,2))
Occurrences are: List((a,2), (b,2)) Result is: List((a,2), (b,1))
Occurrences are: List((a,2), (b,2)) Result is: List((a,2), (b,2))
Starting with: List()
Done with: List() results are: List(List())
Occurrences are: List((a,2), (b,2)) Result is: List((b,1))
Starting with: List()
Done with: List() results are: List(List())
Occurrences are: List((a,2), (b,2)) Result is: List((b,2))
Done with: List((a,2), (b,2)) results are: List(List(), List((a,1)), List((a,1), (b,1)), List((a,1), (b,2)), List((a,2)), List((a,2), (b,1)), List((a,2), (b,2)), List((b,1)), List((b,2)))
Done: List(List(), List((a,1)), List((a,1), (b,1)), List((a,1), (b,2)), List((a,2)), List((a,2), (b,1)), List((a,2), (b,2)), List((b,1)), List((b,2)))
```