# SCALA - Explain flow of this function

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Can anybody explain to me the flow of this function? I thought that, with this code, the result would have been: `List((a,1) (a,2) (b,1) (b,2))`. I do not understand how the result `List((a,1), (b,1))` is achieved.

```
/** Returns the list of all subsets of the occurrence list.
    * This includes the occurrence itself, i.e. `List(('k', 1), ('o', 1))`
    * is a subset of `List(('k', 1), ('o', 1))`.
    * It also include the empty subset `List()`.
    *
    * Example: the subsets of the occurrence list `List(('a', 2), ('b', 2))` are:
    *
    * List(
    * List(),
    * List(('a', 1)),
    * List(('a', 2)),
    * List(('b', 1)),
    * List(('a', 1), ('b', 1)),
    * List(('a', 2), ('b', 1)),
    * List(('b', 2)),
    * List(('a', 1), ('b', 2)),
    * List(('a', 2), ('b', 2))
    * )
    *
    * Note that the order of the occurrence list subsets does not matter -- the subsets
    * in the example above could have been displayed in some other order.
    */
def combinations(occurrences: Occurrences): List[Occurrences] = 
  occurrences.foldRight(List[Occurrences](Nil)) {
    case ((ch, occ), occAcc) => {
      for {
        oA <- occAcc
        count <- 1 to occ
      } yield (ch, count) :: oA
    } ++ occAcc
  }
```

Comment: The input is: List((a, 2), (b,2))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scala Recursive For Comprehension Prepends Empty List Only Once, Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65511406/scala-recursive-for-comprehension-prepends-empty-list-only-once-why)

Answer (score 1):

The only way you're going to develop a deep understanding is by getting your hands dirty, i.e. dig around in it.

Throw in some diagnostic output.

```
def combinations(occurrences: Occurrences): List[Occurrences] =
  occurrences.foldRight(List[Occurrences](Nil)) {
    case ((ch, occ), occAcc) => {
      println(s"case (($ch, $occ), $occAcc) =>")  //<---
      for {
        oA <- occAcc
        count <- 1 to occ
        _ = println(s"yield ($ch,$count) :: $oA") //<---
      } yield (ch, count) :: oA
    } ++ occAcc
  }

val rslt = combinations(List(('a',2),('b',2)))    //build
println("------------")                           //separator
rslt.foreach(println)                             //results
```

Study each `println()`. What do you expect it to show? Study the results. Is it what you expected?

Move the concatenation of the occurrence accumulator from the end of the `case` block, `} ++ occAcc`, to the beginning of the block, `occAcc ++ {`. What changes?

Use different input. [Warning: larger numbers == much more output.]

It takes time, but it's worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

I do not exactly know what this `Occurrences "Type"` and its structure is, but when you pass a List of occurrences ( not meaning the type, for example List('a', 2) it means that character 'a' has occurred twice, right? ), it passes them to the `foldRight` function one by one, and as an initial value ( zero value is a better term ), you pass the empty list of `Occurrences`, and in the second argument you pass an anonymous function which takes and occurrence, which has a character denoted as `ch`, the current occurrence as `occ`, and `occAcc` as accumulator of occurrences, and the rest is pretty straight forward, It's just a for comprehension that for each element in `occAcc` and the count of occurrences, yields the char and the possible count of occurrences and adds it to the final result.

Comment: I think you don't know what the fold functions does, it takes a list of elements, and then folds ( aggregates ) the elements into a single result, for instance if you wanted to determine the sum of all the (integer) elements it would be something like: `list.fold(0) { 
case (a, b) => a + b }`, or simpler: `list.fold(0)(_ + _)`, in your case you are using foldRight which in the second arguments it receives a function from a single tupled element (ch, occ) and the other argument is the accumulator of accurrences.

Comment: Let's take an input: List((a, 2),(b,2)).               
 •STEP1: oA is NULL, count is 1. (b,1) Is added to the list OA. Then the other step (b, 2). Here is my first problem, what happens now?  Does '<-' operator subscribe the previous result ( The accumulator is still NULL so OA <- OACC turns OA null).  After this steps the result is concatenated with OACC ( ++ OACC). Here it comes the second input (a, 2). In this case the accumulator is the result of the previous steps. But I do not see how the result how the previous step should be (b, 1)  or (b, 2)

Comment: STEP1: value ('a', 2) is passed to the function with occAcc = Nil, right? let's see what happens in the for comprehension. occAcc is still empty so it does not generate any oA, in the line after, count generates 1 and 2, right? see what yield returns as the result: ('a', 1) and ('a', 2 ) are added to the occAcc list. in STEP2, ('b', 2) are passeed to the function, in for comprehension you have oA which is the elements inside the occAcc (('a', 1), ('a', 2)) on at a time right? and the count is generated as 1 and 2 ( one at a time again ), and what does yield return? ( see next comment )

Comment: It says yield for instance ('b', 1) to the ('a', 1) and to the ('a', 2) and to the (Nil).
Then add ('b', 2) into ('a', 1), ('a', 2), Nil. So there is your output => 
List( ('a', 1), ('a', 2) ) which are generated from the first iteration, concatenated to List ( ('b', 1), ('b', 2)), ...